# retrieve in the rest of the code the data of an array initiated when displaying a page by a setFormeData()

Tags: javascript

[image: 1]

My final goal is to remove the cross-shaped button when the label does not contain an image with this kind of code:

```
const uploadLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".upload-image"); // labels
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-image");
uploadLabels.forEach((label, i) => {
  if (imagePaths[i] !== null) {
    buttons[i].style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    // const deleteBtn = label.querySelector(".delete-image");
    deleteBtn.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

or something like this:

```
const uploadLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".upload-image"); // labels
uploadLabels.forEach((label, i) => {
  const deleteBtn = label.firstElementChild;
  if (label.style.backgroundImage != "") {
    deleteBtn.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
    deleteBtn.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

For the 1st example imagePaths is empty, see the console.log line 50. the image links are however inserted on page load with 'setFormData'. I think the problem is that imagePaths is declare[] above.
So how to recover imagePaths with links?

For the second example the conditionif (label.style.backgroundImage != "")does not work.
The console.logs oflabel.style.backgroundImagein setFormData return 'url("null")' if no image and url("an image url") if there is an image.
So what should be put in the condition to know if the label contains an image?

Below are the relevant parts of the code:
Code html :

```
<div class="upload-catalouge">
            <input type="file" class="fileupload" id="first-file-upload-btn" hidden />
            <label for="first-file-upload-btn" class="upload-image">
              <button class="delete-image" data-index="0" hidden><img src="../img/close.png" alt="" /></button>
            </label>
            <input type="file" class="fileupload" id="second-file-upload-btn" hidden />
            <label for="second-file-upload-btn" class="upload-image">
              <button class="delete-image" data-index="0"><img src="../img/close.png" alt="" /></button>
            </label>
            <input type="file" class="fileupload" id="third-file-upload-btn" hidden />
            <label for="third-file-upload-btn" class="upload-image">
              <button class="delete-image" data-index="0"><img src="../img/close.png" alt="" /></button>
            </label>
            <input type="file" class="fileupload" id="fourth-file-upload-btn" hidden />
            <label for="fourth-file-upload-btn" class="upload-image">
              <button class="delete-image" data-index="0"><img src="../img/close.png" alt="" /></button>
            </label>
          </div>
```

javascript :

```
let user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.user || null);
let loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
 
// checknig user is logged in or not
window.onload = () => {
  if (user) {
    if (!compareToken(user.authToken, user.email)) {
      location.replace("/login");
    }
  } else {
    location.replace("/login");
  }
};
 
// upload image handle
let uploadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".fileupload");
const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-image");
 
let imagePaths = []; // will store all uploaded images paths;
 
uploadImages.forEach((fileupload, index) => {
  fileupload.addEventListener("change", () => {
    const file = fileupload.files[0];
    let imageUrl;
 
    if (file.type.includes("image")) {
      // means user uploaded an image
      fetch("/s3url")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((url) => {
          fetch(url, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }),
            body: file,
          }).then((res) => {
            imageUrl = url.split("?")[0];
            imagePaths[index] = imageUrl;
            let label = document.querySelector(`label[for=${fileupload.id}]`);
            label.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
            let productImage = document.querySelector(".product-image");
            productImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
          });
        });
    } else {
      showAlert("upload image only");
    }
  });
});
 
console.log(`imagePaths en dessous de window.onload : `, imagePaths);
const labels = document.querySelectorAll(".upload-image");
labels.forEach((label) => {
  console.log(`label.style.backgroundImage for each label :`, label.style.backgroundImage);
});
 
deleteButtons.forEach((deleteButton, index) => {
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    imagePaths[index] = null;
    let label = document.querySelector(`label[for=${deleteButton.parentNode.htmlFor}]`);
    label.style.backgroundImage = null;
    let productImage = document.querySelector(".product-image");
    imageLinks = imagePaths.filter((value) => value);
    productImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageLinks[imageLinks.length - 1]})`;
  });
});
 
// const uploadLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".upload-image"); // label
// const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-image");
// uploadLabels.forEach((label, i) => {
//   if (imagePaths[i] !== null) {
//     console.log("imagePaths", imagePaths);
//     console.log("imagePaths[i]", imagePaths[i]);
//     buttons[i].style.display = "flex";
//     // deleteBtn.style.pointerEvents = "all";
//   } else {
//     // const deleteBtn = label.querySelector(".delete-image");
//     deleteBtn.style.display = "none";
//     // deleteBtn.style.pointerEvents = "none";
//   }
// });
 
// function updateDeleteButtonVisibility() {
//const uploadLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".upload-image"); // labels
//uploadLabels.forEach((label, i) => {
  //const deleteBtn = label.firstElementChild;
 // console.log(`deleteBtn :`, deleteBtn);
 // console.log(`label.style.backgroundImage :`, label.style.backgroundImage);
  //if (label.style.backgroundImage != "") {
  //  console.log(`label in if :`, label.style.backgroundImage);
  //  deleteBtn.style.display = "flex";
    // deleteBtn.style.pointerEvents = "all";
  //} else {
    // const deleteBtn = label.querySelector(".delete-image");
 //   deleteBtn.style.display = "none";
    // deleteBtn.style.pointerEvents = "none";
//  }
//});
 
 
// exisiting product detail handle
 
const setFormsData = (data) => {
  productName.value = data.name;
  shortLine.value = data.shortDes;
  des.value = data.des;
  actualPrice.value = data.actualPrice;
  discountPercentage.value = data.discount;
  sellingPrice.value = data.sellPrice;
  stock.value = data.stock;
  tags.value = data.tags;
 
  // set up images
  imagePaths = data.images;
  console.log(`imagePaths in setFormData :`, imagePaths);
  /* Je met imagePaths dans localStorage */
 
  imagePaths.forEach((url, i) => {
    let label = document.querySelector(`label[for=${uploadImages[i].id}]`);
    label.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
    let productImage = document.querySelector(".product-image");
    // productImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
    imageLinks = imagePaths.filter((value) => value);
    productImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageLinks[imageLinks.length - 1]})`;
    console.log(`label.style.backgroundImage in setFormData :`, label.style.backgroundImage);
  });
 
  // setup sizes
  sizes = data.sizes;
 
  let sizeCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll(".size-checkbox");
  sizeCheckbox.forEach((item) => {
    if (sizes.includes(item.value)) {
      item.setAttribute("checked", "");
    }
  });
};
 
const fetchAddProductDataId = () => {
  fetch("/get-products", {
    method: "post",
    headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
    body: JSON.stringify({ email: user.email, id: productId }),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setFormsData(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
 
let productId = null;
if (location.pathname != "/add-product") {
  productId = decodeURI(location.pathname.split("/").pop());
 
  fetchAddProductDataId();
}
```

css :

```
.upload-image:hover .delete-image {
  opacity: 0.8;
  pointer-events: all;
}
 
.delete-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
 
.delete-image img {
  height: 15px;
}
 
.upload-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
}
 
.upload-image:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

My final goal is to remove the cross-shaped button when the label does not contain an image with this kind of code:

```
const uploadLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".upload-image"); // labels
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-image");
uploadLabels.forEach((label, i) => {
  if (imagePaths[i] !== null) {
    buttons[i].style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    // const deleteBtn = label.querySelector(".delete-image");
    deleteBtn.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

or something like this:

```
const uploadLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".upload-image"); // labels
uploadLabels.forEach((label, i) => {
  const deleteBtn = label.firstElementChild;
  if (label.style.backgroundImage != "") {
    deleteBtn.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
    deleteBtn.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

For the 1st example imagePaths is empty, see the console.log line 50. the image links are however inserted on page load with 'setFormData'. I think the problem is that imagePaths is declare[] above.
So how to recover imagePaths with links?

For the second example the conditionif (label.style.backgroundImage != "")does not work.
The console.logs oflabel.style.backgroundImagein setFormData return 'url("null")' if no image and url("an image url") if there is an image.
So what should be put in the condition to know if the label contains an image?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The gif:
https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2l...NqYN/giphy.mp4
with this code:

```
function  updateDeleteButtonVisibility ( )  { 
  const uploadLabels = document . querySelectorAll ( “.upload-image” ) ; // labels 
  const buttons = document . querySelectorAll ( “.delete-image” ) ;
  uploadLabels. forEach ( ( label, i ) => { 
    if  ( imagePaths [ i ] !== null )  { 
      buttons [ i ] .style.display = "flex" ;
     }  else  { 
      buttons [ i ] .style.display = "none" ;
     } 
  } ) ;
}
```

I call this function when I modify the images, when I delete an image, when the data is loaded when the page is displaying.

with the table initialed like this : let imagePaths = [ null , null , null , null ] ;

this is a gift of the result:
https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2l...NqYN/giphy.mp4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).